# Is Brave private?

Tags: privacy, chromium

I have been using Brave for a long time now. Lately, I realized it uses Chromium. I really dislike using Google because of my data privacy. So I am starting to wonder if Brave does the same thing.

Comment: Chromium is not insecure.

Comment: I'm confused about the basis for your question. Because CompanyA does something you do not like, you suspect CompanyB of doing the same thing? Do you have a basis for suspecting CompanyB?

Comment: @schroeder And yes, I was wondering that because brave runs off of chrominum.

Comment: Chromium is not Google Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brave is not Chrome, and Chrome is not Chromium. Vivaldi is built around Chromium too, and they are very privacy oriented too.

Chromium is the base where Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, and a lot of other niche browsers are built. Google takes Chromium, adds their services, and packages it as Chrome. Brave gets the same codebase, adds its own privacy oriented code, and releases it as Brave.

So if "secure" is about your privacy, Brave is definitely better than Chrome.